# CSS positioning not centering in IE but is in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Hi my friend is having trouble centering the text in the middle of the margins.

When I look at this site in IE 11 it just doesn't seem to center, could some one help me as to why?

```
<header id="site-header" class="site-header valign-center"> 
    <div class="intro">
        <h2>x</h2>
        <p> y </p>
        <h1>z</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-white" data-scroll href="#foo">button</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

The CSS:

```
.site-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../images/backgrounds/header.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.valign-center {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.site-header .intro {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

I've tried `margin: 0 auto;` but it doesn't change.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `html, body { height: 100%; }`

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.site-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../images/backgrounds/header.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.valign-center {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.site-header .intro {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<header id="site-header" class="site-header valign-center"> 
    <div class="intro">
        <h2>x</h2>
        <p> y </p>
        <h1>z</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-white" data-scroll href="#foo">button</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Or you can just use `height: 100vh` on `.site-header`

```css
.site-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../images/backgrounds/header.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.valign-center {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.site-header .intro {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<header id="site-header" class="site-header valign-center"> 
    <div class="intro">
        <h2>x</h2>
        <p> y </p>
        <h1>z</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-white" data-scroll href="#foo">button</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: When you try to position a child in this case .site-header, the parent html/body also has to be defined. Especially when you use percent because CSS will determine the size in reference to the parent.